# Is it possible to use database in App Engine / PHP without Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Google Cloud SQL is expensive, so I want to know if it's possible to use another database system in App Engine / PHP.

Answer (score 1):

App engine has a built-in object db called datastore. It is useful if your application don't need to operate complex query.

Comment: But does it support transactions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's currently a Datastore API for PHP, so Cloud SQL is the only option for the moment - unless you want to run your own MySQL (or other) database on Compute Engine, but I don't imagine that would be cheaper and you would have to manage your own scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with Cloud SQL you only pay for the time that your application is actually accessing the database [1], and that charges start at $0.025/h [2]

1. https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#how_usage_calculated
2. https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing#per_use

Answer (score 0):

You can Export your database in the XML file , and then use simpleXMLElemnent on that XML file. If you dont want to spend money for Google Cloud SQL.